# MySQL: return single record with 50 IDs, instead of a 50 records with a single ID

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table of books.

I can select all the books for a certain author:

```
SELECT BookID FROM tblBook WHERE AuthorID=9

(returns 4 records):

23
63
85
98
```

But what if I want to return a single record, with the ID numbers concatenated like this:

```
23 63 85 98
```

How do I do that?

Using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT group_concat(BookID SEPARATOR ' ') FROM tblBook WHERE AuthorID=9 GROUP BY BookID
```

Comment: here's link to docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat; it supports order by and some other goodies

Answer (score 1):

check out the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.